# LINQ GroupBy, whilst keeping all object fields

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I've currently got this sample table of data:

```
ID  | Policy ID     |   History ID  | Policy name
1   |   1           |    0          | Test
2   |   1           |    1          | Test
3   |   2           |    0          | Test1
4   |   2           |    1          | Test1
```

Out of this, I want to group by the Policy ID and History ID (MAX), so the records I want to be kept are ID's 2 and 4:

```
   ID   | Policy ID     |   History ID  | Policy name
    2   |   1           |    1          | Test
    4   |   2           |    1          | Test1
```

I've tried to do this in LINQ and stumbling on the same issue every time. I can group my entities, but always into a group where I have to re-define the properties, rather than have them kept from my Policy objects. Such as:

```
var policies = _context.Policies.GroupBy(a => a.intPolicyId)
                                            .Select(group => new {
                                                PolicyID = group.Key,
                                                HistoryID = group.Max(a => a.intHistoryID)
                                            });
```

This simply just brings out a list of objects which have "Policy ID" and "History ID" within them. I want all the properties returned from the Policies object, without having to redefine them all, as there are around 50+ properties in this object.

I tried:

```
        var policies = _context.Policies.GroupBy(a => a.intPolicyId)
                                                    .Select(group => new {
                                                        PolicyID = group.Key,
                                                        HistoryID = group.Max(a => a.intHistoryID)
                                                        PolicyObject = group;
                                                    });
```

But this errors out.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a little confused here: If intPolicyID is the primary key of the Policies table, why would you group by it? It will always return every row in the table, because every intPolicyID is unique.

Comment: I think it was just a desperate coding slip by myself to get this working. In reality, I guess it'd only be grouped by the History ID on every row.

Comment: Ok. In this case you cannot group by History ID either. Not sure if you have a customer ID or other field you *really* want to group by. But that's step 1 in this process.

Comment: Re-reading your question I think what you want is for every Policy, you want the latest 'history' object, and you're assuming the largest History ID per Policy is the most recent one. However, are the history items even kept in the policies table? Most likely they're kept in the Histories table or something similar. You should probably _context.Histories.GroupBy( a => a.intPolicyId), because intPolicyID can occur many times in the history table. This is just a guess since I can't see your schema.

Comment: Oh, actually, you may be onto something here that could speed up the queries, I'll try and implement this approach too and check the speed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by composite key

```
_context.Policies.GroupBy(a => new {a.intPolicyId, *other fields*}).Select(
    group=> new {
        PolicyId = group.Key.intPolicyId,
        HistoryId = group.Max(intHistoryId),
        *other fields*
    }
);
```

Another way - grab histories, than join back with the rest of the data, something like this (won't work out of the box, will require some refining)

```
var historyIDs = _context.Policies.GroupBy(a=>a.intPolicyId).Select(group => new {
                                            PolicyID = group.Key,
                                            HistoryID = group.Max(a => a.intHistoryID)
                                        });

var finalData = from h in historyIDs
                join p in _context.Policies on h.intPolicyId equals p.intPolicyId
                select new {h.HistoryId, *all other policy fields*}
```

And yet another way, even simpler and not require a lot of typing :):

```
var historyIDs = _context.Policies.GroupBy(a=>a.intPolicyId).Select(group => new {
                                            PolicyID = group.Key,
                                            HistoryID = group.Max(a => a.intHistoryID)
                                        });

var finalData = from h in historyIDs
                join p in _context.Policies on h.PolicyId equals p.intPolicyId && h.HistoryId equals p.HistoryId
                select p
```

Basically it's somewhat equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
select p.*
from Policy p
inner join (
    select pi.policyId, max(pi.historyId)
    from Policy pi
    group by pi.policyId
) pp on pp.policyId = p.policyId and pp.historyId = p.historyId
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but wouldn't this be the same as what Ive currently got, with me having to enter the *other fields* (thus 50+ properties) in order to get it working?

Comment: The second option would require a trip back to the database, and so 2 round trips in a singular method. I very much appreciate your help here, but surely there's a way of doing this in one trip?

Comment: Not quite right. The first query are not executed right away, it just embedded into the query tree of the second query. So it really should be a single round-trip to the database.

Comment: I *think* this could work after inspecting your code - will report back in 5!

Comment: As long as you don't enumerate the historyIDs var, it won't build / run the query. so performance shouldn't suffer; the database query won't happen until you call .ToList() or foreach on finalData/historyIDs.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ to Objects, I'd do this as

```
var policies = _context.Policies
    .GroupBy(a => a.intPolicyId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.intHistoryID).First());
```

but your `_context` impleis there might be a database involved and I'm not 100% sure this will translate.

Basically it groups by the policy ID as you'd expect, then within each group orders by history ID and from each group selects the row with the highest history ID. It returns exactly the same type as is found in `Policies`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm having problems getting this solution working also. The error is that the query just won't compile, and receiving the error: "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.", that's on .FirstOrDefault(), .First() just fails completely.

Comment: That's odd, I would have expected this to work :( You could try moving the `OrderBy` to _before_ the `GroupBy` but in theory it shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: The reason the timeout happens is likely due to a large dataset/table. Basically for every row in the table, you're querying the database a second time with the .First() call. the First() call forces evaulation for each object in the GroupBy/Select chain which is just a performance destroyer on anything substantial.

Comment: @Richthofen I'd expect the LINQ provider to handle this better, in that case; I'd expect the `OrderBy...First` part to be included as a subquery rather than a batch of followup queries.